# Youtube get camera type

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, computer-vision, youtube-dl

Consider these videos:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_kZ5Lj-59E

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0pdwd0miqs

The first is probably filmed with a mobile phone's camera, the second with a professional one. I would like to determine this difference.

**Q:** Is anybody aware of a way of retrieving information about the camera type that was used for a video on Youtube?

**Q:** Or, is there a more generic way for videos to determine video recording quality?

Comment: Your second video is NSFW?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, the name is misleading, but it is totally SFW.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the camera metadata from a video on YouTube at this point. Theoretically YouTube could capture this information for some videos (and make it available in the future), but not every video file has camera metadata on it.  In fact, a lot of videos use more than one camera.

Technically there are other methods of determining "recording quality", but they won't be perfect.  For example, you could use the assumption that if a video is available in 1080p it might be better quality than one only available in 480p.  However, there can still be a big difference in two videos both available in 1080p.

You can't rely on bitrate either, because YouTube could change the bitrate on you depending on your internet speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine a video is available in HD, for example if you execute this query (API V3): https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?id=L8oEtD_CEs0&part=contentDetails&_h=1&, you'll notice I've recorded it in HD ("definition": "hd"), though I did use my shaky hand and phone camera :) 
For API V2 we have  element described here: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/more-ways-to-find-what-youre-looking.html.